JWT "invalid_token" C#
I am trying to log in using a JWT token. I received the "invalid_token" error when logging in. Tell me what my mistake might be.
I did testing api in Postman
enter image description here
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shared
{
    public static class JwtExtensions
    {
        public const string SecurityKey = "FJGHwjgohjofpwkgjuihjfkowfigjojUIuHIUhiuhIKJFJSHWUIDiu*(83UFJ";
    public static void AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:7029",
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityKey))
            };
        });
    }
    }
}


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication.Model;
using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication.Contexts;
using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication.Services;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Shared;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ApplicationContext _context;
        
        public AccountController(ApplicationContext app) { 
            _context = app;
       
        }
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public ActionResult Register(UserRegister user)
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm aes = new AesManaged();

            byte[] key = aes.Key;
            var role = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.roleId);
            if (role == null) return BadRequest("Role is not found");
            User users = new User()
            {
                Surname = user.Surname,
                Email = user.Email,
                Name = user.Name,
                Username = user.Username,
                Password = EncryptData.Encrypt(user.Password),
                RolesId = user.roleId,
                Roles = role
            };

            _context.Users.Add(users);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            User user = new();
            user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == loginModel.Login
                                               && u.Password == EncryptData.Encrypt(loginModel.Password));
            if (user == null) return NotFound("User is not found");
            var role = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.RolesId);
            if (user is null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtExtensions.SecurityKey));
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expirationTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim("role", role.Role),

        };
            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "https://localhost:7029",
                claims: claims,
                expires: expirationTimeStamp,

                signingCredentials: signingCredentials
            );
            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
            Token token = new Token { Tokens = tokenString, time = (int)expirationTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds };

            return Ok(token);
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            
            return Ok("baseUrl");
        }

      
    }
}


using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication;
using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication.Contexts;
using GoblinWebAPi.Auth.Authentication.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Shared;
using System.Text;

namespace GoblinWebAPi.Auth
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            // For Entity Framework
            string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr");
           
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddJwtAuthentication();

            





        }
        public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            /*app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins("https://192.168.0.100:8081")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();

            });*/
            
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); //Authentication

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();



            app.MapControllers();

          


            app.Run();
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        }
    }
}




I thought the issue was with the issuer, but changing it didn't help. I have the following api host:https://localhost:7029
